# Hide drawable for expandable list when there are no children

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Found some similar questions but no answers that work. Right now I am doing this:

```
private ExpandableListView elv;
elv.setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.expandable_list_icon_selector));
```

**expandable_list_icon_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Unfortunately, this hides the indicator for all groups even if they are not empty. It appears that when a group is not expanded, android considers it empty. Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: This method does not work by design ([source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java;h=8bd797baedae0219ed45f42cda7f83a57408a7af;hb=HEAD#l348)).**

Have you tried to add non-empty state?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true"
          android:state_expanded="false"
          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/some_image"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It will show the indicator when the list is expanded but hide it again when I close the list.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a mistake in the code. Fixed it. So, the idea was to add a drawable for non-empty state file the drawable for empty state must be transparent.

Comment: Ya, I knew what you meant. The drawable for non-empty state only shows up with the list is expanded.

Comment: I looked through the `ExpandableListView` source code and found out that the `ExpandableListView` uses different state depending on whether group is empty or not. I think it's necessary to declare explicitly that we want a transparent drawable only for empty collapsed groups. So, I fixed my answer again.

Comment: I added the code in xml and still no drawable when the list is closed. Also, when empty parents are "opened", the drawable shows up for them too. Any other ideas? I appreciate the help.

Comment: The only idea I have is to create a selector with all possible combinations of `state_empty` and `state_expanded` and find out how the `ExpandableListView` chooses drawables. I have no possibility to run this example right now, but I'll definitely try to do it later.

Comment: Seems it's impossible to achieve desired behavior with current 'ExpandableListView` implementation, because collapsed columns are treated as empty for performance reasons. I updated my answer and added a link to the source.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to your task - to show a custom group indicator next to the group name of only some of the groups. I did it by first hiding the group indicator at all using the method `setGroupIndicator(null)`. Then I implemented a subclass of `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and inside the `getGroupView()` method I showed or hid my own indicator image based on my logic. You may use such an approach, if that is still current. I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's link of working example of Hide drawable for expandable list when there are no children.

Hope this will help you...

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html

Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and i solved it like this:

```
if(explistView != null){
     explistView.setIndicatorBounds(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*

```
in getGroupView() method of adapter  use 

if ( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
       indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    } 
else {`enter code here`
       indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
       indicator.setImageResource( isExpanded ? R.drawable.group_expanded : R.drawable.group_closed );
    }
```

*